# Matrices Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $$ A= 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -6 & -8 & 15 & 0 & 9 \\
    2 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 8 \\
    -8 & 7 & -6 & 9 & 1 \\
    16&6&-22&8&-20\\
    3&-3&11&6&6
    \end{bmatrix}
\ \ \ \ 
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1&14&-4&-2&-7 \\
    -2&-1&-4&-3&4 \\
    -15&4&-1&7&8 \\
    -5&-1&11&6&-1\\
    4&-14&8&-7&9
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
which are both invertible. Define:
$$
C_x=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0&x-8&0 \\
    e^\sqrt{x}&0&log(x)&28&-6 \\
    3&1-x&-8&2&0 \\
    0&0&2&\pi&-1\\
    0&0&1&e^2&2
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$Let \ d(x)=det(C_xAC_x^{-1}ABAB^{-1}A^{-1}C_x)$

What is the set of $x$ for which $d(x)>0$?

I think that the expression may be able to be simplified, $d(x) = det(C_xA)$, although this is with little reasoning. Even with this finding the answer is daunting and would be unsure of what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Binet formula ($Det(AB)=Det(A)Det(B)$) and $Det(A^{-1})=Det(A)^{-1}$ we can compute

$$Det(C_xAC_x^{-1}ABAB^{-1}A^{-1}C_x)=Det(C_x)Det(A)Det(C_x)^{-1}Det(A)Det(B)Det(A)Det(B)^{-1}Det(A)^{-1}Det(C_x)=...=Det(C_x)Det(A)^2$$

Now because $Det(A)^2>0$ you're left with the equation $Det(C_x)>0$.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there would be a trick to simplify it. So for any $x$ that $C_x$ has an inverse, $d(x)>0$.

Comment: Keep in mind that $C_x$ has an invers implies $d(x)\neq0$ and not  $d(x)>0$. Try to compute $d(x)$ using the first row and then the second column.

Comment: I have $x\in\mathbb R\backslash [1,8]$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. So $d(x)=det(A)^2det(C_x)$, so then $d(x)>0, \ where \ det(C_x)>0, \ since \ det(A)^2 >0.$ So now just solve for $det(C_x)>0$

Comment: We also have to check that $\det A \neq 0$, but this is doable (if mildly tedious) by hand with e.g. reducing the matrix to triangular form with row operations and checking that the diagonal entries are all nonzero.

Comment: He stated that both $A,B$ are invertible. W/o this assumption he could not even use Binet like he did.

Answer (score 1):

Your simplification is on the right track. Remember that $\det (M_1 M_2 \cdots M_n) = (\det M_1) (\det M_2) \cdots (\det M_n)$. The quantities $\det M_i$ are just scalars, so their products commute and we can rearrange them however we want to cancel products of the form $(\det M)(\det M^{-1})$. This leaves you $d(x) = (\det C_x)(\det A)^2$.

The $(\det A)^2$ term has to be positive (unless $A$ is singular, which you can easily rule out), so you just need to compute $\det C_x$. The easiest way to do this is to use the definition of the determinant as a sum over permutations. It turns out that this sum only has two nonzero terms, because any nonzero term has to include the entries $1-x$ (only nonzero entry in its column), $x-8$ (only nonzero entry in its row), and $e^\sqrt{x}$ (only nonzero entry in its column besides $3$, which we can't choose because we have to choose $1-x$).